# Java - >> operator?

Tags: java

I have looked on the oracle website, but that seems to advanced for me, please can someone give me a basic run down on what the >> operator is for in java? and maybe a basic example would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`>>` is right bitwise shift.  For example, `5 >> 1` is `2`, because `5` is `101` in binary, and that's shifted right to get `10`.

It's (mostly) equivalent to "divided by two to the", although it's not quite equivalent for negative numbers.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. why do people still vote my question down, isn't this site for asking questions?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't think they should be.  I'd upvote your question if I wasn't out of upvotes for the day.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's probably because googling "Java operators" and looking through the first few results will provide what you asked for (including examples)

Comment: Good point, but like i said in the question the "bitwise operator" wasn't good enough for me, i wanted a simple explanation and a basic exmaple..

Answer (score 2):

This is signed right shift operator. You can look for docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 0):

Please find example here: http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-right-shift.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` is a signed right shift. It basically takes a binary value and shifts it to the right:
Example: `8 >> 2 = 4` which in binary gives `1000 >> 2` (shift `1000` by two positions) = `10` in binary which is 2.